# Pass jsonobject as request parameter using post method volley

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I was just trying to use JsonRequestObject to send values to php script and receive json data but below code is not working

```
package com.demo.volleyjsondemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.demo.volleyjsondemo.Utils.Constants;
import com.demo.volleyjsondemo.Utils.RequestSingleTone;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;
    TextView txtName, txtEmail;
    JSONObject parameters;
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();
        try {
            sendReq();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        context = MainActivity.this;
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    }

    private void sendReq() throws JSONException {

        //just to demonstrate how to send parameters with json request
        parameters = new JSONObject();
        try {
            parameters.put(Constants.NAME, "jack");
            Log.e("paramter",parameters.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //jsonobjectrequest to send request and get response in json
        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST //request method
                , Constants.BASE_URL + Constants.GET_PERSON_DETAILS_URL   //URL of php file
                , new JSONObject(parameters.toString()) //parameters to send to server
                , new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() { //response will come here in case of success
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    Log.e("response", response.getString(Constants.NAME));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {  //response will come here in case of error
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });

        //add request to singletone
        RequestSingleTone.getInstance(context).addRequest(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```

php code

```
<?php
    require_once 'dbconfig.php';


    $name = $_POST['name'];

    //$name="jack";

    $singlePersonInfoQuery = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE name='".$name."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$singlePersonInfoQuery);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $raw = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        echo json_encode(array("name"=>$raw['name'],"email"=>$raw['email']));
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array("name"=>$name,"email"=>"blank"));
    }

?>
```

I am getting following error

```
    10-06 14:36:34.943 5256-5256/com.demo.volleyjsondemo W/System.err: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value perfect<br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
10-06 14:36:34.943 5256-5256/com.demo.volleyjsondemo W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:73)
10-06 14:36:34.943 5256-5256/com.demo.volleyjsondemo W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:123)
10-06 14:36:34.943 5256-5256/com.demo.volleyjsondemo W/System.err: Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value perfect<br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
10-06 14:36:34.943 5256-5256/com.demo.volleyjsondemo W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
10-06 14:36:34.943 5256-5256/com.demo.volleyjsondemo W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
10-06 14:36:34.943 5256-5256/com.demo.volleyjsondemo W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
10-06 14:36:34.943 5256-5256/com.demo.volleyjsondemo W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:68)
10-06 14:36:34.943 5256-5256/com.demo.volleyjsondemo W/System.err:  ... 1 more
```

I guess about above warning is because of wrong way of receiving parameters in php script..Above code working fine if i don't pass any parameters or using stringrequest but i want to use jsonrequestobject..I can't understand what is wrong

Comment: We can't really say from just that code, you need to debug the php script and make sure it always outputs correctly formed json. The java error hints at something amiss in the php response.

Comment: when i use normal $name="jack",It works fine..It is giving me proper json data but i am confused about passing parameters from android and receiving in php.That means name is not passing properly

Comment: by writing length of parameter that receive in file,I found that i am not receiving parameter  because it is showing 0 length..Please help me how can i pass request parameter and use it in php script

Comment: After searching a lot i found problem that i was using wrong method of receiving parameters in php script .. now i am able to receive parameter and get data from database which i have store in file to check and return to android but now facing a new problem                                                                 org.json.JSONException: Value perfect of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally answering my own question,After debugging my php script i found that i done in receiving parameters in php script..As i am sending parameters as jsonobject,No $_POST or $_GET will work.Please refer below which is working fine..I hope it will help someone

android code:-

```
package com.demo.volleyjsondemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.demo.volleyjsondemo.Utils.Constants;
import com.demo.volleyjsondemo.Utils.RequestSingleTone;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;
    TextView txtName, txtEmail;
    Context context;
    Map<String, String> parametersMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();
        try {
            sendReq();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        context = MainActivity.this;
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    }

    private void sendReq() throws JSONException {

        //just to demonstrate how to send parameters with json request
        parametersMap.put(Constants.NAME, "jack");

        //jsonobjectrequest to send request and get response in json
        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST //request method
                , Constants.BASE_URL + Constants.GET_PERSON_DETAILS_URL   //URL of php file
                , new JSONObject(parametersMap) //parameters to send to server
                , new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() { //response will come here in case of success
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.e("response","received");
                try{
                    txtEmail.setText(response.getString(Constants.EMAIL));
                    txtName.setText(response.getString(Constants.NAME));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {  //response will come here in case of error
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });

        //add request to singletone
        RequestSingleTone.getInstance(context).addRequest(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```

php code:-

```
<?php 
    require_once 'dbconfig.php';
    $name = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true); //sending json object from android..can not receive parameters using $_POST or $_GET

    $singlePersonInfoQuery = "SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `name`='".$name['name']."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$singlePersonInfoQuery);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $raw = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    }else{

    }
    echo json_encode(array("name"=>$raw["name"],"email"=>$raw["email"]));
?>
```