# JSON response Not Working, don't know the issue

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, android-volley

In the App, I need to perform a login by entering a username and a password which will be passed checked in the database, I already succeed doing it by not using JSON only by checking the response given by PHP, but I need to retrieve all the data and thought it will be great using JSON. 
Here is the android studio code and after that the php code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button_login;
    EditText username,password;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);

        button_login = findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);



        button_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                login();
            }
        });
    }

    public void login() {
        String json_url = "https://app.jetransporte.ma/android/loginjson.php";
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();
        params.put("username", username.getText().toString());
        params.put("password", password.getText().toString());

        JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject(params);
        final JsonObjectRequest JsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, json_url, parameters,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject> () {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


                        try {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                            String usname = json.getString("username");
                            String usid = json.getString("user_id");
                            String correct = json.getString("correct");
                            if(usid.contains("1")){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SelectorActivity.class);

                                startActivity(intent);
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Login ou Mot de passe Incorrecte",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){

        };

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(JsonObjectRequest);


    }
}
```

What I Want to perform is retrieving data from mysql database which gives a json object with those brackets {} when trying to access it directly on the browser using GET method,

Here is the PHP code

```
<?php 
include "../db/db.php"; // $db->conn

$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "username");
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password");
$query= $db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username = 'saad' ");
$countin = $query->rowCount();

if($countin>0){
    $fetchin= $query->fetch();      
    $json = json_encode($fetchin);
    echo $json;
}else{
    $fetchin['correct']="0"; 
    $json = json_encode(array("correct" => $fetchin["correct"]));
    echo $json;
} 
?>
```

Any Help Please, I'm new to android studio and java and really wish to make it work

Comment: Did you get any log in logcat?

Comment: In the Logcat I find this message : org.json.JSONException: No value for username.  If I simply delete that line of "String usname " then I get "No value for user_id "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already got the `JSONObject` in `onResponse` method. I don't know why you create empty `JSONObject` there. Please remove this and try like below:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

    try {
        String usname = response.optString("username");
        String usid = response.optString("user_id");
        String correct = response.optString("correct");

        if(usid.contains("1")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SelectorActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Login ou Mot de passe Incorrecte",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried this solution but nothing happening again when clicking on the sign in button. I will manage to find out how to get some informations with Logcat and come back to you

Comment: That means you didn't follow my code. Please carefully follow my code. Use `optString` instead of `getString`. Replace your code with my one

Comment: Thank you so much, the solution is working. However it seems like the parameters value are not sent to the php page, I don't know why???

Comment: Check your logic in server side. Current problem is in there

Comment: YES, A server side problem, it worked like magic by using json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true); Thks again!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, After using the help provided by  Md. Asaduzzaman. I was able to make the action working in the app. but after that, none of the parameters sent to the php script was working. so the solution was to get the parameters this way :

$param = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
$username = $param["username"]; $password = $param["password"];

Instead of $_POST["username"]

More info about this : [Pass jsonobject as request parameter using post method volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46612072/pass-jsonobject-as-request-parameter-using-post-method-volley)